# Android cannot resolve Material Components

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I am getting this error:

> Cannot resolve symbol
>   '@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox'

I am getting this error after I added this line to my TextInputLayout in my XML:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox"
```

This is my full XML code(removed unrelevant constraints/margins):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="300">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/cheese_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/cheese_description" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

this is my app **build.gradle**:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.cheese.cheese.some.sample_cheese"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my other **build.gradle**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried:

- changing buildToolsVersions from "27.0.3" to "27.0.2" and sync
- Invalidate Caches/ Restart
- Rebuild Project

I took the XML line of code that causes error [from the material.io components here](https://material.io/components/android/catalog/text-input-layout/). does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/) have not yet shipped new releases under the `com.android.support:design` dependency as of yet (or via any other official dependency you can include in your `build.gradle` file) so what you're seeing in `27.0.2` does not contain any of the recent changes - such as support for `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox`.

You'll have to copy the portions of the Material Components library you want directly into your project if you want access to the latest changes.

Comment: Thank you! do you have a guide on how to accomplish that? I am just starting out

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't quite as straightforward as one would like - you'd want to copy the [lib directory](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib) into the root of your project, then edit your `settings.gradle` to most of the code from [their settings.gradle](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/settings.gradle). Personally, I'd probably just stick to the things already launched as part of the `com.android.support:design` dependency, particularly if you are just starting out.

Answer (score 8):

Both of answers are right but i found an error by the codelabs given code on this link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-111-kotlin/#2
The OutlineBox is misspelled the correct code is

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use new packaging for support libraries you should use:

`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01` dependency for that

Answer (score 4):

add below dependency solved my problem

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

my full dependencies is

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Somehow off-your-question, but to clarify on the Material stuff (it can help anyone on migrating to the Material Design intro),

Change your app theme to inherit from a Material Components theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

for more information visit

[Getting started with Material Components for Android](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 2):

This style is from the part of design support library v28 alpha version and it is not released yet until android p release. For to use this change compileSdkVersion to 'android-P' and use this dependency to use it

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your AndroidManifest.xml file, you have a materialcomponents as theme for your Activity.
Some thing like this:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting same issue I solved using below `dependencies`

Use Below `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3
```